# Beginning learner of Altium. I need help fixing an Engineering Control Order error that says “unknown pin and failed to add component”

Tags: altium

[image]

Hello, I am having trouble with Engineering Change Order. When I try to validate on ECO, I keep getting an error “x” mark and the ECO won’t fix it. I have the correct components placed in the right location (pcb.library and pcb.schematic). I don’t seem to see any issue with the schematic layout as image provided. How can I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a footprint for that component?

Answer (score 1):

The footprint for the resistor doesn't exist (or Altium can't find it).  Ensure that the resistor has a vaild footprint assigned.

Also, annotate the schematic so the reference designators are R1, D1, J1 rather than R?, D?, J?.